# Range of the integral of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, definite-integrals

Given $$g(x) = \int_0^{x} \sqrt{1+\sin t} dt -\sqrt{1+\sin x}$$
I would like to show that $g(x) \geq 2\sqrt{2} -10,\,\forall x\in \left(0,\infty\right)$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is very much not a trigonometry problem.  This is a calculus and optimization problem.

Comment: What have you tried?  What has you stuck?  Have you had Calculus?  Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC)?  Do you see that the FTC allows you to differentiate the integral to find the critical points of $g$?

Comment: @Eric Tower I am B.Tech and M.Tech Mechanical, I used $(Sin (x/2))^2+(Cos(x/2))^2$=1$ and then i got result g(x)=-1/2(Cos (x/2)+1/2(Sin(x/2)+1/2-Sin(x/2)-Cos(x/2) and then tried to convert it into trignometric form but getting different result for g(x)

Comment: Do you have to get the lower bound $2 \sqrt{2} - 10$ or would a tighter lower bound suffice?

Comment: Yes i need to get the lower bound , although it is in books but for better understanding i need to prove it by getting the exact value

Comment: The exact value of $$ \inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^+} g(x) $$ is $-1$, not $2\sqrt{2}-10$, so I guess it is a bit difficult to derive the exact steps for proving such loose bound, without being in your instructor's head. To prove the optimal inequality is easier, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

$\int \sqrt{1+\sin t} \, dt=\int \dfrac{\sqrt{1+\sin t}\sqrt{1-\sin t}}{\sqrt{1-\sin t}}\,dt=\int \dfrac{\cos t}{\sqrt{1-\sin t}}\,dt$

Substitute $\sin t=u \to \cos t\, dt = du$

$\int \dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1-u}}=-2 \sqrt{1-u}+C=-2\sqrt{1-\sin t}+C$

thus $\int_0^x \sqrt{1+\sin t} \, dt=-2 \sqrt{1-\sin x}+2$

therefore $g(x)=-2 \sqrt{1-\sin x}+2-\sqrt{\sin x+1}$

$g'(x)=-\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{1-\sin x}-2 \sqrt{\sin x+1}\right)$

and we have $g'(x)=0$ when

$\sqrt{1-\sin x}-2 \sqrt{\sin x+1}=0$

that is $\sqrt{1-\sin x}=2 \sqrt{\sin x+1}=0$

and squaring both sides

$1-\sin x=4(\sin x +1)\to \sin x =-\dfrac{3}{5}$

$g''(x)=\frac{1}{4} \left(2 \sqrt{1-\sin (x)}+\sqrt{1+\sin (x)}\right)$

and $g''\left(-\arcsin \dfrac{3}{5}\right)=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{5}}+\dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{10}}>0$ so at $\sin x =-\dfrac{3}{5}$ the function $g(x)$ has a minimum

$g\left(-\arcsin \dfrac{3}{5}\right)=2-\sqrt{10}$

and in conclusion we can say that

$g(x)\geq 2-\sqrt{10}$ for any $x>0$

as $ 2\sqrt{2} -10<2-\sqrt{10}$ we can also say that

$g(x) \geq 2\sqrt{2} -10$

even if I suspect that there is a typo somewhere

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

$\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+\sin t}\,dt$ is clearly a non-negative, differentiable and increasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.
The minimum of $g(x)$ occurs at a zero of $g'(x)$, and since $g'(x)=\sqrt{1+\sin x}-\frac{\cos x}{2\sqrt{1+\sin x}}$, the minimum value of $g(x)$ is attained at some point such that $1+\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\cos x=0$, or
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\sin x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\cos x = \sin\left(x-\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} $$
so the first interesting point is $x=\pi+\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}+\arcsin\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}=\pi+\arctan\frac{1}{2}+\arctan 2=\frac{3\pi}{2}$, at which $\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}$ equals zero, $g(x)$ is positive and $g'(x)$ has a jump discontinuity. Not a minimum for sure. The second interesting point is 
$x=2\pi+\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}-\arcsin\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}=\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\arctan\frac{1}{2}$ or $x=2\pi-\arctan\frac{3}{4}$, at which $\sqrt{1+\sin x}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}$. We have $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin t}\,dt=4\sqrt{2}$ and

$$ \int_{0}^{\arctan\frac{3}{4}}\sqrt{1+\sin t}\,dt = \int_{0}^{2\arctan\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{1+\sin t}\,dt = 2\int_{0}^{\arctan\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{1+\sin(2z)}\,dz $$
equals:
$$ 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}\,dt=2\int_{0}^{1/3}\frac{1+t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt =2-2\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}$$
and the given function is positive at $x=2\pi-2\arctan\frac{1}{3}$, too. The other interesting points provide larger values, hence the minimum of the given function is attained at $x=0$ and trivially equals $-1$:
$$ \forall x\geq 0,\qquad g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+\sin t}\,dt-\sqrt{1+\sin x}\geq -1.$$
Additionally, $g(x)$ roughly behaves like $-1+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\pi}x$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$:

[image]